# your host may have disabled the mail() function

Tags: mail, xampp, wordpress

After installing lampp, I have this error on a website (a wordpress locally hosted) trying to send an email:

```
The e-mail could not be sent.
Possible reason: your host may have disabled the mail() function.
```

Could this be related to system or only to xampp libs/configuration ?
What kind of solutions do you suggest ? 
Configuring gmail SMTP with xampp seems to be a good solution also.

Answer (score 0):

In order to perform the php `mail()` function you need to either configure it correctly and on linux you most likely need a sendmail program installed. Since `sendmail` is a quite bloated piece of software, there is a simple and lightweight alternative called `nullmailer` which can relay your mail to e.g. your ISP's SMTP server.

Comment: Ok, I will try it, but in this case xampp uses linux server libs and not its own libs !? I was thinking that it is a small webserver with its own environment